# angular2 ngFormControl select not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

my code fragment in .ts file

```
this.signUpForm= _fb.group({
    'fname': ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,NdFormValidation.alphaOnly])]
    'lname': ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,NdFormValidation.alphaOnly])],
    'gender':['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,NdFormValidation.gender])]
});
this.fname = this.signUpForm.controls['fname'];
this.lname = this.signUpForm.controls['lname'];
this.gender = this.signUpForm.controls['gender'];
```

my code fragment in .html file

```
<form [ngFormModel]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signUpForm.value)">

     <div class="input-field">
         <label for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" [ngFormControl]="fname" placeholder="John"/>
         <span *ngIf="fname.hasError('required') && fname.dirty">First name is required</span>
         <span *ngIf="fname.value.length>2 && fname.hasError('invalidAlphaOnly') && fname.dirty">Alphabets and space are only allowed </span>
     </div>

     <div class="input-field">
         <label for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="txtLastName" [ngFormControl]="lname" placeholder="Martin" />
         <span *ngIf="lname.hasError('required') && lname.dirty">First name is required</span>
         <span *ngIf="lname.value.length>2 && lname.hasError('invalidAlphaOnly') && lname.dirty">Alphabets and space are only allowed </span>
     </div>


     <div class="input-field">
         <label for="cmbGender">Gender</label>
         <select id="cmbGender" [ngFormControl]="gender">
             <option *ngFor="#sex of genders" [value]="sex" >{{sex|uppercase}}</option>
         </select>
         <span *ngIf="gender.hasError('required') && gender.dirty">Gender is required</span>
         <span *ngIf="gender.hasError('invalidGender') && gender.dirty">Gender can be male,female or other</span>
     </div>

     <button [disabled]="!signUpForm.valid || signUpForm.pristine" [class.nd-btn-disabled]="!signUpForm.valid || signUpForm.pristine" id="loginButton" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
     <button id="signUpButton" [routerLink]="['LoginPage']" type="button" title="Click to login with your existing account">Already have an account?</button>

 </form>
```

My problem

ngFormControl and validation is working as expected in fname and lname but for gender when i change value of select it is always in ng-pristine(not  in ng-dirty state) and ng-invalid

```
<div class="input-field" _ngcontent-ybk-5="">
    <label _ngcontent-ybk-5="" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
    <input id="txtLastName" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" type="text" _ngcontent-ybk-5="" placeholder="Martin">
</div>

<label _ngcontent-ybk-5="" for="cmbGender">Gender</label>
<select id="cmbGender" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" _ngcontent-ybk-5="">
```

Why change made to `<select>` element is not triggering..... I can't figure out what's the problem, anybody who can help me or point out what i am missing

**As per martin comment**

I ensure that signUpForm.value is not reflecting the the change in `<select>` control by adding following code

```
get checkSignUpFormModel() { return JSON.stringify(this.signUpForm.value); }
```

out put of `{{checkSignUpFormModel}}` is

{"fname":"max","lname":"pay",,"gender":""}

Although my change to fname and lname text box is being reflected in `{{checkSignUpFormModel}}`  but change to gender has no affect

NdFormValidation.gender goes like this

```
static gender(control:Control){
        console.log('sex',control.value);
        if( control.value.match(/^(male|female|others)$/))
            return null;
        else
            return {"invalidGender":true};
    }
```

Comment: I think we need more information to help you. Are you sure changes in the select box aren't triggering? Select some option in the select box and then see what's in the form controls with `this.signUpForm.value`. Is the value updated? Where the `NdFormValidation.gender` validator comes from? To me it seems like just the validator isn't correct. I'm using select boxes the same way as you do in Angular@beta.6 and it works fine. Also can you make a plnkr or jsfiddle :)?

Comment: Could you provide the content of your custom validator for gender? Thanks!

Comment: Works fine https://plnkr.co/edit/gBpl99?p=preview

Comment: see my updated question for more details

Comment: Still working fine https://plnkr.co/edit/gBpl99?p=preview

Comment: thanks @Gunter  for the plnkr .... Its working there  but not in mine....  
can you suggest what  I am missing then...

Comment: Difficult, I have no way to see what is different in my Plunker and your code. I built the Plunker from the code provided in your questino.

Comment: @Gunter in gender validation function console.log(control.value) is returning empty string like this   sex (an empty string)

Comment: Not in my Plunker. Console output is "sex male", "sex female", ...

Comment: yes, I am talking about mine ... ok I will double check everything and will come back soon.. Thanks

Comment: @Gunter... Problem was with  latest version of Firefox( Firefox 44 on Ubuntu Linux) ....  LOL :D :P :)

Comment: Ok. If two people have different results in Plunker it's usually the browser.